# How To Preview Multiple Images Multiple div Before Upload - jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap Modal for uploading multiple images. When the User Click 'Add-Product-Image' Button, it will generate a new image upload input-form, and when the user selects an image it will instantly show an image below the upload button. My code works fine but I have a little issue.

***My issue:***
When the User Click 'Add-Product-Image' Button, it will generate a new image upload input-form then select the image and new image replace the first image. I want to show the multiple images

```
<div class="product-image">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="Image-upload">
            <span class="image-option-close">&times;</span>
            <label for="product_images"> Upload Image </label>
            <img src="" id="image"  class="h-100" alt="">
            <input type="file" id="product_images[]" accept="image/*" name="product_images" onchange="readURL(this);">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>



$(function () {
        $(this).on('click', '#add-product-image', function () {
            var form = '<div class="form-group"><div class="Image-upload"><span class="image-option-close">&times;</span><label for="product_images" class="">Upload Image</label><input type="file" id="product_images" accept="image/*" name="product_images[]" onchange="readURL(this);"></div></div>';
            $('.product-image').append(form)
        });

        $(this).on('click', '.image-option-close', function () {
            var target_input = $(this).parent();
            target_input.remove();
        })
    });

function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Please See the gif file
https://i.postimg.cc/MG3njJBS/ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif

Answer (score 1):

I think I missunderstood, what you mean is add jquery handling right? this  is no relate to laravel but why you tagged laravel? maybe this will help

```js
$(function () {
        $(this).on('click', '#add-product-image', function () {
            var form = '<div class="form-group"><div class="Image-upload"><span class="image-option-close">&times;</span><label for="product_images" class="">Upload Image</label><input type="file" id="product_images" accept="image/*" name="product_images[]" onchange="readURL(this);"></div></div>';
            $('.product-image').append(form)
        });

        $(this).on('click', '.image-option-close', function () {
            var target_input = $(this).parent();
            target_input.remove();
        })
    });

function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var newimage = $('#image').clone()
                    .attr('src', e.target.result);
                                $('.product-image').prepend(newimage)

                    
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="product_images" accept="image/*" name="product_images" onchange="readURL(this);">


<div class="product-image">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="Image-upload">
            <span class="image-option-close">&times;</span>
            <label for="product_images"> Upload Image </label>
            <img src="" id="image"  class="h-100" alt="">

           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

**old answer:**

You need different name attribute for each file input or you can simply it by using array. just add suffix [] to the name attribute. example:

```
<input type="file" id="product_images" accept="image/*" name="product_images[]" onchange="readURL(this);">
```

then in your controller write something like this:

```
foreach(request()->product_images as $image){
    $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image>move(public_path() . '/mytestfile/', $name); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is my mistake and I update it but my main problem is I can't show multiple images

Comment: Having same id is not a good practice - There is no point cloning an element. `id's` must be unique for each elements in the DOM.

Comment: Your new Code working but here is a little issue. Can you use "(this)"functional.i want this type of code $(this).parent().find('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);

Comment: @ShafayetAl-Anik do you want use one `img` preview section and add more previews the same img ?

Comment: No, I Have Multiple img Sections. When I click the Add New Image button it will generate a new input Tyle="file" With New img Tag. Then I want to select an img file in new input type=" file" and the image will show newly generated img tag. My New Generated Tag Code Image [link](https://i.postimg.cc/x19b7Sbs/Capture.png)

Comment: @ShafayetAl-Anik Okay i undertand. You should carefully look at my answer - its working in the snippet - Upload the first it will show up - then Click add New products and it will new `div` then that image will be shown in that newly generated div. Please refer to my answer carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use a `class` selector for your `img` preview not an `id` - since the `id` must be unique for each `element` in the DOM.

Secondly, to `preview` each `image` respectively after clicking on `Add-Product-Image` you need add its own `img` element so that we can use this inputs `img` preview in that relevant section.

To get the actual `img` and the `closest` input we need to use jQuery `Prev()` method.

```
$(input).prev('img.image').attr('src', e.target.result)
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(this).on('click', '#add-product-image', function() {
    var form = '<div class="form-group"><div class="Image-upload"><span class="image-option-close">&times;</span><label for="product_images" class="">Upload Image</label><br><img src="" class="image"style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" alt=""><input class="form-control" type="file" id="product_images[]" accept="image/*" name="product_images[]" onchange="readURL(this);"></div></div>';
    $('.product-image').append(form)
  });

  $(this).on('click', '.image-option-close', function() {
    var target_input = $(this).parent();
    target_input.remove();
  })
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(input).prev('img.image').attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-image">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="Image-upload">
      <span class="image-option-close">&times;</span>
      <label for="product_images">Upload Image </label>
      <br>
      <img src="" class="image" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" alt="">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="product_images[]" accept="image/*" name="product_images" onchange="readURL(this);">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="add-product-image" class="btn btn-success">Add-Product-Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(this).on('click', '#add-product-image', function() {
    var form = '<div class="form-group"><div class="Image-upload"><span class="image-option-close">&times;</span><label for="product_images" class="">Upload Image</label><br><img src="" class="image"style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" alt=""><input class="form-control" type="file" id="product_images[]" accept="image/*" name="product_images[]" onchange="readURL(this);"></div></div>';
    $('.product-image').append(form)
  });

  $(this).on('click', '.image-option-close', function() {
    var target_input = $(this).parent();
    target_input.remove();
  })
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(input).prev('img.image').attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-image">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="Image-upload">
      <span class="image-option-close">&times;</span>
      <label for="product_images">Upload Image </label>
      <br>
      <img src="" class="image" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" alt="">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="product_images[]" accept="image/*" name="product_images" onchange="readURL(this);">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="add-product-image" class="btn btn-success">Add-Product-Image</button>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).